# How to save a html element as a png

Tags: javascript, html, css, png

Not a duplicate as I need to convert to a html canvas, not from one

---

I am developing a site that puts some elements on the screen.

I need to be able to capture the content of a `<div>` in a png

I have tried some chrome extensions but none worked unfortunately

```
            <style type="text/css">
            * {
                margin: 0px 0px;
                padding: 0px 0px;
            }
            #box {
                background: #FFFF00;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
            }
            </style>
            <div id="box">
            This is my box :)
            </box>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) can help you.

From official web site:

> This script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of
>   it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM
>   and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it
>   does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on
>   the information available on the page.

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('box'), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  },
  width: 400,
  height: 400
});
```

Click [here](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) to see some live examples.

Comment: This does the basic job but when I use it with Google Charts I get a message up version of the image.
What I am looking for is a sort of snipping tool that can clip on to elements and turn them into a canvas.

Comment: html2canvas is very buggy.  Not all elements get saved.  There has to be a better way.